# Plot a barchart after pandas.value_counts()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, histogram

I have a dataframe with several columns and I need to plot a graph based on the number of counts in the 'Total'column.

I performed the following code:

```
df['Total'].value_counts()
```

The output are as follows:

```
2   10
20  15
4   8
8   20
```

This means the the number 2 appears in the Total columns 10 times, number 20 appears 15 times and so on.

How do I plot a barchart with the x-axis as the number itself and the y-axis as the occurances and in ascending
order? The x-axis will plot 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 20.
What are the next steps after:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as an example:

This denoted your 'Total' column -> `[2,2,2,2,2,20,20,20,20,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,8]`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections

total = [2,2,2,2,2,20,20,20,20,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['total'])

#print(df.value_counts())

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df['total'].value_counts().plot(ax = ax, kind = 'bar', ylabel = 'frequency')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: but you are hardcoding the total. what if i have hundreds of figures?

Comment: That was an example since I do not have access to your dataset. You should be able to get the results just using this:
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df['total'].value_counts().plot(ax = ax, kind = 'bar', ylabel = 'frequency')
plt.show()

df['total].value_counts() will give you the frequency for all unique values.

Comment: what do you mean by figures?

Comment: the list of values inside total is huge

Comment: Just try using the lines that i have pasted in my previous comment. This should work.